# How to cancel and restart a C# Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, cancellation-token

I have a long running, long interval, polling process. I need to be able to force an update and restart the polling.

The  most obvious thing that came to mind was to cancel the polling task, and start a new one since the initial loop always updates.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, using OperationCanceledException to control program flow seems weird to me - but perhaps it's the right choice? This is what I have at the moment:

```
 public void Start()
 {
     var previousDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

     CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     CancellationToken = CancellationTokenSource.Token;

     ASMTask = Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         try
         {
             while (!CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
             {
                 if (CheckForUpdate())
                 {
                     Update(previousDateTime);
                 }

                 await Task.Delay(PollingInterval * 1000, CancellationToken);
             }
             CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
         }
         catch (OperationCanceledException oc)
         {
             Start();
         }
     }, CancellationToken);

 }

 public void ForceUpdate()
 {
     CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
 }
```

Also not sure how calling Start() inside the task will affect resources? I'm guessing it's fine since the new task will be given a thread to execute in?

I wanted to do something like:

```
public void ForceUpdate()
{
    CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    ASMTask.WaitForCancellationComplete();
    Start();
}
```

But I can't see a way to wait for the Task to complete by cancellation.

---

EDIT: RE - Duplicate question.

The accepted answer to the previous question was using exceptions in the same way that I was trying to avoid, it does turn out however that the second answer was useful but I didn't realise that until after reading the explanation provided by [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson).
I'm happy for this to be closed as a duplicate, although I can't figure out how to actually do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here, so I'm going to propose a different approach.

Firstly, I note that the calls to `CheckForUpdate()` and `Update()` are synchronous, so it's probably not that useful to use `await` for the delay - so I'll use a different way of delaying while still allowing the delay to be interrupted.

I'll also split the main method into two - an outer controlling loop and an inner processing loop.

You don't mention any way to control the longevity of the outer loop, so I'll use a cancellation token to control that.

I've put this together in a compilable console app that demonstrates the approach. Note that because this is a console app, I'm not awaiting the task I used to start the Control Loop. In real code, you'd await this somewhere.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent _restart = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(10000); // Cancels after 10s.
            var task = Task.Run(() => ControlLoop(2, cancellationSource.Token, _restart));

            // After 5 seconds reset the process loop.

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Restarting process loop.");
            RestartProcessLoop();

            // The cancellation source will cancel 10 seconds after it was constructed, so we can just wait now.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for control loop to terminate");
            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Control loop exited.");
        }

        public static void RestartProcessLoop()
        {
            _restart.Set();
        }

        public static async Task ControlLoop(int pollingIntervalSeconds, CancellationToken cancellation, AutoResetEvent restart)
        {
            while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => ProcessLoop(pollingIntervalSeconds, cancellation, restart));
            }
        }

        public static void ProcessLoop(int pollingIntervalSeconds, CancellationToken cancellation, AutoResetEvent restart)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning ProcessLoop()");

            var previousDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

            var terminators = new[]{cancellation.WaitHandle, restart};

            while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(terminators, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pollingIntervalSeconds)) == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
            {
                if (CheckForUpdate())
                {
                    Update(previousDateTime);
                    previousDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ending ProcessLoop()");
        }

        public static void Update(DateTime previousDateTime)
        {
        }

        public static bool CheckForUpdate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking for update.");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you. The while in my situation needs to be do-while, as I want the code to execute once immediately on activation.

Comment: @DavidKirkpatrick I guess you can adjust it as desired. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can make `Start` an `async` method (where I've added a line to simulate an error exception)

```
    static int count;
    public async Task Start()
    {
        var previousDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken = CancellationTokenSource.Token;
        try
        {
            while (!CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (CheckForUpdate())
                {
                    Update(previousDateTime); // or better await UpdateAsync(previousDateTime);
                }

                await Task.Delay(PollingInterval * 1000, CancellationToken);
                Debug.WriteLine("here " + count);
                if (count>3)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    throw new Exception("simulate error");
                }
            }
            CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(oc.Message);
        }
    }
```

and then call it from an event like

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ASMTask = Start();
        await ASMTask;
    }
```

To cancel and restart the `Task` use

```
    public async Task ForceUpdate()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await ASMTask;
        count++;
        ASMTask = Start();
        await ASMTask;
    }
```

again from an event handler

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ASMTask != null)
        {
            try
            {
                await ForceUpdate();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Write(exc.Message);
                ASMTask = Start();
                await ASMTask;
            }
        }
    }
```