# How to restart a task in c#? or How to restart Thread.Sleep()?

Tags: c#, winforms, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have been trying to make a Windows application, in which when I receive a message 'some_string' (from a server) I need to change the color of label (sys2lbl in code) to green and it shall stay green for 15 seconds and then turn red. However, for example,  during the 5th second if I receive the message 'some_string' again, then the label should stay green for 15 seconds more i.e. 5+15 = 20 in total.

I'm using Task.Run(), as per my understanding, this task shall be restarted somehow when I receive the string 'some_string' within these 15 seconds.

Note: This Task runs perfectly if I receive 'some_string' after 15 seconds.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    if (x.ApplicationMessage.Topic == "some_string")
    { 
        sys2lbl.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        sys2lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
});
```

Comment: My understanding of `Thread.Sleep()` is that it literally sleeps the thread you're interacting with. You can't do anything else with that thread until the time frame passes- This is why Thread.Sleep isn't necessarily a great idea in a lot of cases. Looks like you may want some behavior from the `Timer` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0

Comment: What does *when I receive a message from a server* mean, in practice? Are you polling an API or the Server pushes it? I.e., do you have sort of a *Message Loop* that dispatches to the UI Thread? Or is it event driven? Asynchronous? -- If you need to start a background Thread to poll the Server, you need a delegate invoked in the UI Thread. That's where you set a Control's state (not from another Thread / Task). You can use a Timer, in the UI Thread, and increase its `Interval` by 5 seconds if it's still active, otherwise just start it. -- If you actually need a different Thread.

Comment: The UI that I have been making subscribes to the topics in an MQTT server. So, the messages are published in the server in a random manner.  Whenever I subscribe to a particular topic the label should turn green and stay like that for a while and then turn red.

Comment: So, are you subscribing to specific topics using a Broker's publishing capabilities? You should then receive a new message through an event, which is raised in a Thread other than the UI Thread. You can use a delegate created in the UI Thread to marshal the new data to the UI Thread. You could either use an `IProgrsss<T>` delegate or `Invoke()` / `BeginInvoke()` your own delegate (you need to test whether the synchronous version is more reliable than the asynchronous here) when the event is received. The delegate, as described , either starts a Timer or increases its Interval.

Comment: BTW, instead of tagging your question with irrelevant `cancellationtoken` or such (as if you were *suggesting* a solution), why don't you tag it `mqtt` and post the code you're using to receive the Publisher's notifications? Is your Client also a Publisher? I.e., you may have some *race conditions* there that you need to address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart a completed task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791493/restart-a-completed-task) and [How to cancel and restart a C# Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558624/how-to-cancel-and-restart-a-c-sharp-task)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Timer` from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. In your form declare

```cs
private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();
```

Initialize it like this

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer.Interval = 15000; // Milliseconds
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    sys2lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Then you can start or restart the timer with

```cs
private void RestartTimer()
{
    _timer.Stop();
    sys2lbl.BackColor = Color.Green;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

I often use this technique to delay the execution of a query. As an example, let us assume that we have a data grid and a textbox used to filter the data in the grid. In the `TextChanged` event of the textbox we start the timer with a short delay (e.g., 200 ms). In `Timer_Tick` we stop the timer and re-query the data.

The advantage is that the data is re-queried without the user having to hit Enter or to click a button. But on the other hand, the data is not re-queried after every keystroke, which could be problematic if the query execution is slow.

If the user types the next character before the timer delay elapses, the timer is restarted. If the query is executed while entering the filter because the user is typing slowly, the next keystrokes will be accumulated and then inserted in the textbox all at once when the data update is completed. This reduces the number of re-queries and makes the UI more responsive.

Note that in Windows Forms, events are executed strictly sequentially. A new event will never interrupt a method (which can be an event handler) running on the UI thread. Therefore, you will never have multithreading issues with a timer.